I am new in Angular 2. I have tried to create a component but I got this error
Here's my app.component.ts file :
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: false,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'frontend';
}


My ProjectListComponent file
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from '../../services/project.service';
import { Project } from '../../models/Project';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list',
  templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {

  projects: Project[] = [];

  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectService.getProjects().subscribe(data => {
      this.projects = data;
    });
  }

}


The app.module.ts file
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProjectListModule } from './components/project-list/project-list.module';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ProjectListModule  
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


And the angular component I try to use in my app.component.html : <app-project-list />
The errors :

If app-project-list is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If app-project-list is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

PLEASE HELP !

If you add the ProjectListComponent in the declarations array of ProjectListModule, it is only accessible within that particular module.
Inorder to share this component with other modules, when the module is imported.
You should make use of exports array. which exposes it outside the module.
This applies for pipes, components, directives.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProjectListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [ProjectListComponent]
})
export class ProjectListModule { }

